# How to combine multiple ranges in one variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, global-variables, var

I have this globalVariables function with a variable array:

```
function globalVariables(){ 
 var varArray = {
   spreadsheetId   : 'MY_SPREADSHEET_ID',
   dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:P', // Where I want to include another range
   idRange         : 'Air Database!B2:B',
   lastCol         : 'S',
   insertRange     : 'Air Database!A1:P1',
   sheetID         : 'MY_SHEET_ID_#'
 };
return varArray;
}
```

On dataRange above, I want to skip columns D & E. I want it to be something like:

```
dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:C,F2:P',
```

I've tried what I wrote above but it returned blank (even the A2:C didn't show up). I've also tried the ones I listed below and all of them returned the same thing (blank). aws is my sheet

```
dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:C' & 'Air Database!F2:P',
dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:C&F2:P',
dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:C && F2:P',
dataRange       : 'Air Database!A2:C','Air Database!F2:P',
dataRange       : ['Air Database!A2:C','Air Database!F2:P'],
dataRange       : aws.getRangeList(['A2:C', 'F2:P']),
dataRange       : [aws.getRange('A2:C'), aws.getRange('F2:P')],
```

**UPDATE:** No need to answer the question since I already just worked around the problem. If in case you do have tips for other people with the same problem, feel free to answer. Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getRangeList(String)

Comment: @Cooper thanks! but I don't know if I'm understanding it right (sorry I'm new at this) but I've tried (aws is my sheet) aws.getRangeList(['A2:C', 'F2:P']), and it returned blank

Answer (score 2):

My Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 | 4 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 9 | 16 | 17 | 2 |
| 10 | 17 | 0 | 11 | 10 | 5 | 6 | 17 | 10 | 16 |
| 8 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 16 | 17 | 2 | 16 | 15 | 0 |
| 14 | 13 | 17 | 12 | 5 | 2 | 13 | 9 | 11 | 14 |
| 0 | 4 | 15 | 4 | 9 | 3 | 14 | 8 | 16 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 19 | 17 | 14 | 8 | 19 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 18 | 9 | 2 | 6 | 7 | 16 | 13 | 13 | 8 | 0 |
| 12 | 9 | 9 | 15 | 17 | 12 | 1 | 1 | 18 | 14 |
| 8 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 15 | 18 | 2 | 16 | 17 | 3 |
| 19 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 13 | 7 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 17 | 11 | 13 | 6 | 19 |
| 1 | 9 | 3 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 12 | 8 | 10 | 14 |
| 19 | 14 | 6 | 18 | 2 | 17 | 13 | 2 | 4 | 18 |
| 11 | 16 | 2 | 14 | 2 | 17 | 17 | 13 | 5 | 9 |
| 10 | 10 | 12 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 6 | 4 | 12 | 11 |
| 3 | 10 | 16 | 14 | 13 | 17 | 2 | 9 | 15 | 13 |
| 10 | 7 | 0 | 15 | 13 | 3 | 13 | 19 | 17 | 10 |
| 18 | 8 | 14 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 12 | 18 | 12 | 8 |
| 15 | 17 | 7 | 17 | 4 | 3 | 18 | 1 | 7 | 6 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 19 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 0 |

Rangelist Code:

```
function myfunc() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(['Sheet0!A2:C', 'E1:J']);
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => {
    let arr = r.getValues().filter(r => r[0]);
    Logger.log('Range: ' + r.getA1Notation())
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  });
}

Execution log
11:27:09 AM Notice  Execution started
11:27:10 AM Info    Range: A2:C
11:27:10 AM Info    [[7,8,4],[10,17,0],[8,4,12],[14,13,17],[6,3,19],[18,9,2],[12,9,9],[8,4,18],[19,3,12],[6,5,3],[1,9,3],[19,14,6],[11,16,2],[10,10,12],[3,10,16],[10,7,0],[18,8,14],[15,17,7],[11,3,3]]
11:27:11 AM Info    Range: E1:J
11:27:11 AM Info    [["COL5","COL6","COL7","COL8","COL9","COL10"],[14,14,9,16,17,2],[10,5,6,17,10,16],[16,17,2,16,15,0],[5,2,13,9,11,14],[9,3,14,8,16,1],[14,8,19,0,0,1],[7,16,13,13,8,0],[17,12,1,1,18,14],[15,18,2,16,17,3],[18,2,4,3,13,7],[6,17,11,13,6,19],[9,2,12,8,10,14],[2,17,13,2,4,18],[2,17,17,13,5,9],[6,3,6,4,12,11],[13,17,2,9,15,13],[13,3,13,19,17,10],[9,8,12,18,12,8],[4,3,18,1,7,6]]
11:27:11 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you for all this! Although I tried, and it still won't work for the global variables function. This would be very useful if I were to change the whole code for the web app. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Yeah I would recommend that you don't use global variables.  Just get use to doing some extra typing it's not a big deal because global variable get reset with every function call unless you know how to do lazy loading.  TheMaster has an explanation about it.  I have a global object that I use for global variables and it takes it's input from a spreadsheet hash table and properties service.  I'm not interested in explaining it.

Comment: The above code was just an example of how to use rangeLists

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Yeah the global variables kind of messed up what I already know. No worries, I'll just search for what you mentioned. Thank you again!!